# Getting newer GCC version in Ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I want to get newer GCC version. How to do that from ternimal?
I am getting this:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: [This link](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) may be helpul.

Comment: You may find the [toolchain-r ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=bionic) useful. See also [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu)

Comment: download configure make make install